# Bisection method in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, recursion, numerical-methods, bisection

I am trying to solve an equation using Bisection method. However, when I try to run this, I get the below error

```
"Error in if ((fn(kVec, tVec, b) * fn(kVec, tVec, a) > 0) | (b > a)) { : 
  argument is of length zero"
```

## Bisection method routine

```
bisect<-function(kVec,tVec,fn,b,a,tol=1e-15){
  i<-0
  r<-(b+a)/2
  res<-c(i,r,fn(kVec,tVec,r))
  if ((fn(kVec,tVec,b)*fn(kVec,tVec,a)>0)|(b>a)) {
    return('Improper start values') }
  else
    while (abs(fn(kVec,tVec,r))>tol) {
      i<-i+1
      if (fn(kVec,tVec,b)*fn(kVec,tVec,r)>0) {
        b<-r
        r<-(b+a)/2 
      }
      else {
        a<-r
        r<-(b+a)/2 
      }
      res<-rbind(res,c(i,r,fn(kVec, tVec,r)))  
  }
return(res)
}
```

## Function to define the equation

```
FCfunc<-function(kVec,tVec,b){
for(i in 1:k){
    ((kVec[i]*(tVec[i]*exp(-tVec[i])-tVec[i-1]*exp(-b*tVec[i-1])))
    }
}
```

## Calling bisection routine with some initial estimates

```
bisect(kVec,tVec,FCfunc,0.00001,10.00001,tol=10e-16)
```

Comment: Function `FCfunc` is not returning any value (returns NULL). In `bisect` the `if` expression is evaluated to `NULL > 0` and returns the error.

Comment: @bergant It's just a definition of a equation rite. I followed the same steps for a different equation with just tVec and it worked. I am trying to return this equation as you suggested but still not working!

Comment: There is a `for` loop inside the FCfunc. Do you want to return a *sum* of values for i = 1..k ?

Comment: @bergant Yes Bergant. The second part of my equation looks something like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwisrte63ubcio1/Screenshot%202015-03-15%2014.48.36.png?dl=0

Comment: So you should correct the FCfunc to return this expression (as I don't have a clue what InterFail is). Try calling, testing and debugging FCfunc directly before you move to the bisection. Also, vectors in R don't have values at index 0, start with value 0 at index 1: `tVec <- c(0, 2.45, 4.9, ` and when iterating do it from i = 2.

Comment: I did the changes you mentioned. However, Now I am left with this error.       "Error in if ((fn(kVec, tVec, b) * fn(kVec, tVec, a) > 0) | (b > a)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Comment: it means that some of values in if expression are NA. I still think you should test the FCfunc if it returns the right values. If you correct the function, update it in the question.

Comment: This resolved my issue. However, I am unable to mark this as answered .. what could be the issue ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#bisection method
a<--give trial value-;a
b<--give trial value;b
f<-function(x){-give function-}
f(a)
f(b)
c<-(a+b)/2;c
while(f(c)!=0&&b-a>.00002)
{
    if(f(c)==0)
    {
        c
    }
    if(f(c)<0)
    {
        a<-c
    }
    else
    {
        b=c
    }
    {
        c<-(a+b)/2;c
    }
}
c
```

Comment: can you explain your answer a bit rather than just posting code. It will help them learn :)

Comment: Note that this answer assumes the function is increasing, and will give the wrong answer if the function is decreasing. (Also it will give the wrong answer if there is no root in the specified interval.)

Answer (score 1):

## Bisection Method

```
    rm(list=ls())
    x0<-0
    x1<-1
    e<-0.001 #Error of tolerance
    fun<-function(x)(x^3-9*(x^2)+18*x-6) # An example function
    y0<-fun(x0);y0
    y1<-fun(x1);y1
    x2<-x1
    i<-1
    if(sign(y0)==sign(y1)){

        print("Starting vaules are not suitable")
    }else
    {
        while(fun(x2)!=0){
            x2<-(x0+x1)/2

            y2<-fun(x2)

            if(sign(y1)==sign(y2)){x1<-x2}else{x0<-x2}
                y0<-fun(x0)
                y1<-fun(x1)
                cat(i,x2,"\n") #Print the value obtained in each iteration next line 
                i<-i+1
            }
        }
```

The above while loop stop for that value of x2 for which the function becomes exactly equal to zero, now if you want to allow error at want the answer at the shortest iteration you can replace the condition while(abs(fun(x2))>0.001)
and run the entire program. where 0.001 indicates the margin of error allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will find my bisection method code in R useful

```
f.acc <- function(x){
1+1/x-log(x)
}
f.acc(0.5)
f.acc(6)
# since f.acc is continuous, it must have a root between 0.5 and 6.
x.left <- 0.5
x.right <- 6
iter <- 1
tol <- 1e-6
max.iter <- 100
while ((abs(x.right-x.left) > tol) && (iter < max.iter)) {
x.mid <- (x.left+x.right)/2
if (f.acc(x.mid)*f.acc(x.right)<0) {
x.left <- x.mid
} else {
x.right <- x.mid
}
iter <- iter + 1
cat("At iteration", iter, "value of x.mid is:", x.mid, "\n")
}

cat("At iteration", iter, "value of x.mid is:", x.mid, "and the function value is",
f.acc(x.mid),"\n")

x.n.minus.1 <- 0.5
x.n <- 6
iter <- 1
while ((abs(x.n-x.n.minus.1) > tol) && (iter < max.iter)) {
x.n.plus.1 <- x.n - f.acc(x.n)*(x.n-x.n.minus.1)/(f.acc(x.n)-f.acc(x.n.minus.1))
x.n.minus.1 <- x.n
x.n <- x.n.plus.1
iter <- iter + 1
cat("At iteration", iter, "value of x.n is:", x.n, "\n")
}

cat("At iteration", iter, "value of x is:", x.n, "and the function value is",
f.acc(x.n),"\n")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer is at least in the correct tag, but note that you are not only answering to the OP. Future readers must find this helpful as well, and because of that some explanation would help a lot. Either in text around the code, or in comments within the code. Do read the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide from the help centre; you'll have a better time here for it!

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of bisection method with recursion:

```
bisection <- function(a, b, f, tol=1e-4) {
  stopifnot(sign(f(a))*sign(f(b)) == -1)
  m = (a + b) / 2
  # print(m)
  if ((abs(f(m)) < tol) | (abs(m - a) < tol)) return (m)
  return (ifelse(sign(f(a)) == sign(f(m)), bisection(m, b, f), bisection(a, m, f))
}

bisection(1, 6,  function(x) (x-1/3)*(x+2/3)*(x-3)) # find the root 3 for the cubic polynomial
# [1] 3.5
# [1] 2.25
# [1] 2.875
# [1] 3.1875
# [1] 3.03125
# [1] 2.953125
# [1] 2.992188
# [1] 3.011719
# [1] 3.001953
# [1] 2.99707
# [1] 2.999512
# [1] 3.000732
# [1] 3.000122
# [1] 2.999817
# [1] 2.999969
# [1] 3.000046
# [1] 3.000046

bisection(0, 1,  function(x) (x-1/3)*(x+2/3)*(x-3)) # find the root 1/3 for the cubic polynomial
# [1] 0.5
# [1] 0.25
# [1] 0.375
# [1] 0.3125
# [1] 0.34375
# [1] 0.328125
# [1] 0.3359375
# [1] 0.3320312
# [1] 0.3339844
# [1] 0.3330078
# [1] 0.3334961
# [1] 0.333252
# [1] 0.333374
# [1] 0.333313
# [1] 0.333313

bisection(-1, 0, function(x) (x-1/3)*(x+2/3)*(x-3)) # find the root -2/3 for the cubic polynomial
# [1] -0.5
# [1] -0.75
# [1] -0.625
# [1] -0.6875
# [1] -0.65625
# [1] -0.671875
# [1] -0.6640625
# [1] -0.6679688
# [1] -0.6660156
# [1] -0.6669922
# [1] -0.6665039
# [1] -0.666748
# [1] -0.666626
# [1] -0.666687
# [1] -0.666687
```

The following animations show how the bisection method finds different root for the given function, given different intervals to search from, as input:

[image]

[image]

[image]